# I am passing body in payload to a POST method, which are selected filters. Is this possible to now send any array category if it is empty

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

So this is what I am passing:

```
coCodes:[]
formTypes:["940R", "940"]
quarters:["1", "2", "3", "4"]
years:["2019", "2018"]
```

so coCodes is empty. Is there any way to just pass the other 3 filled arrays only if an array is empty? Or may it be 2 or 1?

Here is it my POST Method:

```
export function POSTFilter(url: string, payload): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      fetch(url, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, credentials: 'same-origin', method: 'post', body: JSON.stringify(payload) })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {

              const allTypesList = json.data;
              resolve(allTypesList);
            });
        } else {
          response.json().then((jsonError) => {
            const errors = jsonError && jsonError.exceptionMessages ? jsonError.exceptionMessages : [];
            const infos = jsonError && jsonError.info ? jsonError.info : [];
            reject([...errors, ...infos]);
          }).catch(() => reject(undefined));
        }
      })
      .catch(() => reject(`Could not fetch ${url}`));
    } catch (ex) {
      reject(`Unexpected error for ${url}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Let's say you have variables `coCodes`, `formTypes`,`quarters` and `years` with some value. You can just check the length and assign the property to the `payload` object only if its length is greater than 0.

So e.g in the line `coCodes.length > 0 && (payload.coCodes = coCodes)`
`payload.coCodes = coCodes` will only execute if `coCodes.length > 0` is true

```
const coCodes = []
const formTypes = ["940R", "940"]
const quarters = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
const years = ["2019", "2018"]
const payload = {}

coCodes.length > 0 && (payload.coCodes = coCodes)
formTypes.length > 0 && (payload.formTypes = formTypes)
quarters.length > 0 && (payload.quarters = quarters)
years.length > 0 && (payload.years = years)

console.log(payload)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is not good way. if there are more vars to pass then you need to write same type of code again.  horrible!!!

Comment: I agree but pre-mature refactoring and optimization is bad. It is unecessary here as per the question.